# name of the company is going out of the background of the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the City name and the company name displayed inside the navigation bar. Below is what I have:

[image]

This is the code for displaying City name and Company name:

```html
<body style="background-color:cadetblue">
         <header>
                <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:100%; ">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
                            <a href="https://www.test.com/">
                                <img src="~/Img/test.png" alt="AJY" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
        
                            </a>
                            <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">City of Testing</span><br />THIS IS TESTING TESTING TESTING</span>
                            
                        </span>
                        <a href="https://www.test.com/">
                            <img src="~/img/home-icon-white.png" alt="Home" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
    </body>
```

when I try to view the above city name and company name on mobile device, it looks like this:

[image]

The last part of the testing is coming outside the dark blue color, #264653, and coming in the cadet blue color in this screen shot. I want the entire name inside the dark blue color on mobile device. I tried to put the company name inside the span tag with the width of 100%, but that did not fix the issue. This is what I tried to do:

```
 <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">City of Testing</span><br /><span style="width:100%">THIS IS TESTING TESTING TESTING</span>THIS IS TESTING TESTING TESTING</span>
```

How can I make the entire company name come inside the color #264653 and not extending to cadetBlue color

This is the entire code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] Package</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mobomo/sketch.js/master/lib/sketch.min.js"></script>


    @*<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>*@
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>
<body style="background-color:cadetblue">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:100%; ">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
                    <a href="https://www.test.com/">
                        <img src="~/Img/test.png" alt="ACR" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />

                    </a>
                    <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">City of Testing</span><br />THIS IS TESTING TESTING TESTING</span>
                    
                </span>
                <a href="https://www.test.com/">
                    <img src="~/img/home-icon-white.png" alt="Home" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-5">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The code works fine, but when viewing on mobile device "THIS IS TESTING TESTING TESTING" comes outside the darker blue area

Comment: Do you want the darker blue area to cut off the text, wrap the text, or just not shrink which would make the lighter blue area smaller?

Comment: I want the darker blue area to cover the entire text.

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. It doesn't really show the issue you are describing... so that makes it hard to fix if there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it.  Can you provide some code that actually reproduces the issue?

Comment: I have put the entire code on the page. The code works fine, but when viewing on mobile device "THIS IS TESTING TESTING TESTING" comes outside the darker blue area

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what your screenshot shows. The code you just added looks like this when I emulate a mobile device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyY7O.png

Comment: I am not sure why it is showing on my phone text coming out of the darker blue